# How to change list to CSV, and vice versa, in PHP

Tags: php, html, csv, html-lists

I have a text file like....

> arfc@net.xz
>
> editor@magazine.com
>
> nafi@cyber.net
>
> nau@times.com
>
> jai@mail.com

I want to convert it to CSV with the help of a little bit PHP, and I want to know also how it can be reversed...ie from CSV to an ordered, or un-ordered list.....kindly help me please :)

Comment: Ordered list in PHP? Did you mean an array, or or a HTML list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert to CSV

```
$data=file_get_contents("file");
$data =explode("\n\n",$data);
echo implode(",",array_filter($data));
```

Update as required to convert from CSV,

```
$data = explode(",", file_get_contents("file") );
echo implode("\n\n",$data);
```

For many rows of csv data, you can iterate the file using [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). eg

```
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2048, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: hey...you are the man!....this does the exact trick of converting list to CSV...thanks!

it would be extra good...if you can tell the reverse as well.. :)

Comment: $data = file_get_contents("csv"); $data = explode(",",$data); echo implode("\n\n",$data);   is the exact inverse :P

Comment: now everything is fine...except one...that the out put from CSV to list is as :

"abc@xyz.com 123@789.com qaz@wsx.com 
1.abc@xyz.com
2.123@789.com
3.qaz@wsx.com"


....when it shud be like

"1.abc@xyz.com
2.123@789.com
3.qaz@wsx.com"

i know it is the easy one to solve...just cant get through it...admitting being a n00b in PHP... :/

Comment: so you only want unique emails list? then you have to write extra code to do that. Maybe try using array_unique(). Always refer to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//read file
$content = file_get_content($filteredFilePath);

//explode contents into array
//if you use windows or mac, newlines may be different
//i.e: \r, \r\n
$list = explode("\n\n", $content); 

//iterate over the items and print a HTML list
//to generate ordered list, use: <ol>
echo '<ul>';
foreach($list as $item) {
    echo '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

**Edit**: I made some modification to work with double newlines.

Comment: I have a file named data.txt and this php script file...in the same dir....and am using $fileContents = file("data.txt"); in place of your 3rd line...as I am guessing i have to provide the external file path somewhere.... :) ....and I thought that will work...but due to my absolute beginning phase, I cudnt be able to find why it is not working....what it is showing is just a single bullet...or in ordered list case, just "1."..... :S

Comment: Cool!...apart from ghostdog74 script, this one is working too!